# NetBeans Platform Unit Test Library Dependencies

Tags: netbeans, junit, jmock

I am working on a Netbeans Platform RCP application.

I use **jmock** in my unit tests and I have created a Library Wrapper Module to import the necessary libraries.

The Module has an section named '**Libraries**' and another section named '**Unit Test Libraries**'.

I hoped that I could add the JMock Library Wrapper to the 'Unit Test Libraries', however when I run the unit tests I get the error '**package org.jmock does not exist**'.

If I import the JMock Library Wrapper in to the main 'Libraries' element then it works, but this feels wrong.

Maven allows me to specify unit-test only dependencies, and I assumed that NetBeans Platform did the same. Should this be possible? Am I doing something wrong? Should I resign myself to a run-time dependency on the unit-test libraries (ugh).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue.  After doing a **"Clean and Build All**" on the project (not the module), everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using library wrappers as test dependencies ought to work; in fact this is how JUnit itself is packaged. Try a clean build as previously suggested.